# copy-dependency; just copy dependencies of a module, not all dependencies of project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

How can I get all dependencies ***of a module (not all dependencies of project)*** in maven? I want when I run 'package' phase of a module, (for example) Hibernate and its dependencies be copeid in a seperate folder inside target folder.
I've googled a lot, my choises are:

1. maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependency (not solved my problem because I don't want all dependencies of project)
2. maven-dependency-plugin:copy (not solved my problem because It just copy the includes one)

should I generate my own plugin!? any idea ?

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: What does that mean: I don't want all dependencies of project (Have you checked the docs http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) how you can influence the things like scope, exclude, transitive etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by module? What do you mean by project?

Comment: @khmarbaise : yes, ofcourse. I've studied and tried to use maven-dependency-plugin. And as I said before, I've tried 'copy' goal. and also tried 'copy-dependencies' (for example 'excludeScope') but none of them was not solving my broblem.

Comment: @Michal Kalinowski : I think I use the words badly! sorry; When I say project, I mean the module that i wat runnig it's POM, and when I say module, I mean the module that I've specifeid to 'dependency:copy' as 'artifactId'